# Duplicate products in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I use Magento 1.8.1 and I don't find a feature to duplicate or clone products. Is there a core solution? Or are there extension to use?

On Magento Connect I didn't find modules have this feature.

I tryed to search on internet but no answer about this question.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Just edit a product in the backend and you should see a `Duplicate` button at the top. Click it.

Comment: Thank you @Marius but I don't see this button on edit product in backend. But I checked the code in the backend and I seen the button with a css class set to "display: none". This problem created from a SEO module that I installated time ago.